# How to install APE (Monkey's Audio) in Mint Rosa?

Tags: package-management, audio

I would like to be able to manipulate `.ape` files in Linux Mint Rosa. However, there seems to be no Monkey's Audio package in the standard repositories (at least with that name).

So my question is: How can I install the Monkey's Audio packages in Mint Rosa?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that manipulate means you edit not just play it. Then audacity is a suitable tool. You can find it in http://www.audacityteam.org/. It can edit other file format too.